# text processing (TM package) R

Tags: r, tm

The end goal of my task is to have a bag-of-words for the write in field of my analysis, merged in with the rest of the spreadsheet associated.

I have a DF(df) with three variables A_id , B_text , D_integer. The script below does all of the text processing fine (to my knowledge), but i forgot to leave in the A_id variable so I could merge the bag of words back with the rest of the spreadsheet. How would I modify the code below so at the end of the analysis I have the bag of words, and the associated A_id for each observation. This way I could merge the bag of words with the Dintdata described below.

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)

Btextdata<-df[,("B_text")]
Dintdata<- df[,c("A_id","D_integer")]
Btextdata2<-as.character(Btextdata$A_id)



#first write in field in nps data
Content0 <-  Corpus(VectorSource(Btextdata2))
npswhyidk<-tm_map(Content0, PlainTextDocument)
npswhyidk2<-tm_map(npswhyidk,removeNumbers)
# deleted rest of tm_map statements

#turning corpus into bag o words
npswhyuser <- TermDocumentMatrix(npswhyidk2)
```

Comment: Can you use `npswhyuser2 <- DocumentTermMatrix(npswhyidk2)` instead, and then `cbind(df, npswhyuser2)`?

Comment: With the cbind how do I ensure that it is correctly merging the data sets together. I feel it is possible they could not be aligned correctly if there are missing values in some of the rows. The code you provided did work though.

Comment: It's because `Corpus(VectorSource(Btextdata2))` does not change the document order, and neither does `DocumentTermMatrix(npswhyidk2))`. The columns of the dtm correspond to the documents in your `df`, which is why you can column-bind (`cbind()`) them back to the document-level variables in `df()`. I encourage you to try **quanteda** as an alternative text package, since it manages document variables very naturally in the corpus and makes the sort of operation you are seeking even easier.